# Django queryset operations order

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to order a queryset and then filter the ordered set. Should this work? Or is it required that the order_by is the last operation in the chain?

for example

```
qs.order_by(books_count).filter(author="bob")
```

is this the same as?

```
qs.filter(author="bob").order_by(books_count)
```

I'm not getting the same results between the two.

Comment: What results are you getting? I'm not sure, but filtering after the order might mean the default ordering is reapplied

Comment: You could find out by applying qs.ordered on your first queryset and see whether the order is prevailed (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.ordered)

Comment: I just did a test with `order_by` before and after, and both produced the same SQL and the same results - neither with any problems. Is `books_count` an actual variable or just missing quotations?

Comment: thanks for confirming - the problem was with my data itself.

Comment: You should write an answer confirming that order doesn't matter for anyone who comes upon this post later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - as per the comments above, the order in which you apply filters (filter, order_by) does not matter.